# How to set a where clause filter with doctrine2 query buider in a many-to-many relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, query-builder

I've been trying with no success to user doctrine2 query builder to fetch records in a related many-to-many table using a where clause.

I would like to reproduce the following statement:

```
SELECT [...] FROM Company
JOIN CompanyAddress ON CompanyAddress.CompanyId = Company.Id
JOIN Address ON Address.Id = CompanyAddress.AddressId
WHERE Address.State = ?
```

following some ideias found on google, stackoverfow and doctrine docs:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('c')
    ->from('Company', 'c')
    ->where(':State MEMBER OF c.Address')
    ->setParameter('State', $arguments);
```

but the results are not the desired one. Any help? Thanks..